# How to set a component many times in JFrame Form

Tags: java, jframe, textfield, repaint

I tried setting text field two times in JFrame Form but last Text Field that I setted remain. Apart from JFrame Form I can set more times successfully. For example

```
class test extends JFrame {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test t = new test();
    textfield.setText("Hello");
    long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long c = a;
    while (c > a - 1000) {
        a = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }
    textfield.setText("Hello2");
}
static private JTextField textfield;
public test() {
    super();
    setSize(300, 300);
    textfield = new JTextField("Hello1");
    add(textfield);
    setVisible(true);
}}
```

Code above is running succesfully. First display "Hello" and then "Hello2" after one second. But in the JFrame Form, only display "Hello2" instead of "Hello".

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    jTextField1.setText("Hello");
    long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long c = a;
    while (c > a - 1000) {
        a = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }
    jTextField1.setText("Hello2");


}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(deneme.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(deneme.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(deneme.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(deneme.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new deneme().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Also I searched `repaint()`, `validate()` and `revalidate()` methods. But because of my project is JFrame Form, there is no JFrame object. Thus, I can not use these methods.

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not running"? Please explain current behaviour and the behaviour you expect.

Comment: can you please be more accurate on what you want your program to do ?

Comment: @KrzysztofKosmatka I mean that text field display only "Hello2". I expect that display "Hello" then "Hello2" after one second. Thanks

Comment: @whyn0t I updated it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in second case `jButton1ActionPerformed()` method is invoked on event dispatching thread (EDT) and you block this thread for a second. If EDT is blocked, UI is not updated. If you want the text to change after a second, you should not block EDT, but use some backgroung thred, e.g.:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed( java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt ){

    jTextField1.setText( "Hello" );
    new javax.swing.SwingWorker< Void, Void >() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception  {
            Thread.sleep( 1000 );
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            jTextField1.setText( "Hello2" );
        }
    }.execute();   
}
```

And do not use active waiting (`while (c > a - 1000)`). Use `Thread.sleep()` instead.

Comment: clean and effective, thanks Krzysztof Kosmatka ; @ K. Talha : keep it up =]